# Is it possible to derive a the 2D inverse FFT algorithm using an existing 1D FFT algorithm?

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I am a complete signal processing newbie, and I apologize in advance for asking a clueless question.

Is it possible to reuse an existing 1D FFT algorithm to compute an the 2D inverse FFT algorithm ?

Comment: I suggest this question be moved to dsp.stackexchange.com.  The theory is more closely tied to the goals of that site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Yes***.  In practical terms, a 2D FFT is 1-D FFTs columnwise then rowwise (or vice versa). This is exactly what I've done [in the past](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft)

### Linear Algebra

From a linear algebra sense; consider the 1D DFT as a [unitary linear transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator)   F. 
The 2D FFT of a square matrix X is simply

```
F*X*F'
```

### making an IFFT from an FFT

If you have no 1D IFFT then make one from an FFT: `IFFT(x) == conj( FFT( conj( x ) )`.  This follows from its [unitarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator):

Note: for the composition of 2D IFFT from 1D FFTs, there are 4 levels of conjugation. The middle two undo each other and can be skipped.

### Scaling Factors

For the fft to be [unitary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator), it should preserve [norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29).  [Many](http://www.fftw.org) [libraries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft) and [tools](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) neglect this and incur a sqrt(N) scale factor on the forward transform which they undo on the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this solution in java that I wrote.. FFT is tricky, but I wrote this as simply as I could for understanding purposes. I won't post the complex class, but it's pretty standard - just holds a double for the real component and a double for the imaginary - and has a host of mathematical operations on complex numbers.

For the direction parameter pass in -1 for forward, and 1 for reverse. That's all the inverse relationship comes down to in this implementation. And of course, you know to inverse a 2D - you simply apply the 1D inverse against the rows, and then against the columns. (or vice versa).

```java
//performs the FFT on a single dimension in the desired direction through recursion
    private static Complex[] RecursiveFFT(Complex[] input, double direction)
    {
        int length = input.length;
        int half_length = input.length / 2;
        Complex[] result = new Complex[length];

        if(length==1)
        {
            result[0] = input[0];
        }
        else
        {
            Complex[] sum = new Complex[half_length];
            Complex[] diff = new Complex[half_length];

            Complex temp = new Complex(0.0, direction*(2*Math.PI)/length).GetExponential();
            Complex c1 = new Complex(1,0);
            Complex c2 = new Complex(2,0);

            for(int index=0;index<half_length;index++)
            {
                sum[index] = input[index].Add(input[index+half_length]).Divide(c2);
                diff[index] = input[index].Subtract(input[index+half_length]).Multiply(c1).Divide(c2);
                c1 = c1.Multiply(temp);
            }

            Complex[] even = RecursiveFFT(sum,direction);
            Complex[] odd = RecursiveFFT(diff,direction);

            for(int index=0;index<half_length;index++)
            {
                result[index*2] = even[index];
                result[index*2 + 1] = odd[index];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The transform of a two-dimensional matrix is simply the composition of the individual transforms of all of the rows and, after all the rows are transformed, the individual transforms of all the columns.

However, there are a number of performance issues in an FFT. In particular, transforming the columns of an array is likely to encounter cache thrashing problems. And performing individual transforms is less efficient than using SIMD parallelism on machines that support it. So it is usually better to write a two-dimensional implementation with performance details in mind than it is to compose a two-dimensional FFT out of one-dimensional FFTs.