# FFTW: Only interested in real result

Tags: c++, c, fft, sse, fftw

I am using FFTW to compute the inverse DFT of 2-dimensional complex data. The output of the default-setup (complex-to-complex) is complex, imaginary parts are not zero. However, I am only interested in the real-part of the result, not in the complex part. The interleaved-real-complex output of FFTW is not ideal for me since I want to postprocess the (real) output via SSE. Is there a way to get an only-real array from FFTW? The Complex-To-Real plans don't seem to work since the output isn't real.

Comment: The concept behind FFT is to get complex data, so why would you try real-part only.

Comment: The question should be: Are you interested in value or phase?

Comment: I suggest moving this question to dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Real data in [time|freq] domain implies [conjugate symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_real-input_DFT) about zero in the other domain.
By enforcing conjugate symmetry (adding conjugate flipped version of itself), you can efficiently discard the imaginary part in the other domain.  This should allow you to use the real ifft in FFTW, getting roughly 2x speedup.  Note you only use nfft/2+1 bins for the FFTW real ifft.

Here's a 1D example to illustrate the point:

```
X = randn(8,1)+j*randn(8,1);
Xsym = .5*(X + conj(X([1 8:-1:2]'))); % force the symmetric condition
err = real(ifft(X)) - ifft(Xsym);
```

For a 2D IFFT, it may be best to perform the 2d ifft with 2 passes of 1d ifft [as described in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349424/is-it-possible-to-derive-a-the-2d-inverse-fft-algorithm-using-an-existing-1d-fft/17365251#17365251)